# Texture is not clear enough nor sharp ,i need help for a project

Tags: rendering, texturing, uv

I was trying every trick I know to make the texture show up sharp and crisp, the picture in the UV map viewport is not the same as the render, i must have missed something.

the result I am looking for is this .....

[image]

and this is my problem here, i am sure it's something simple and easy, but i cant seem to figure it out

[image]

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Make sure your UV map doesn't stretch the image. Otherwise create a texture with higher resolution.

Comment: will its 4k so i am pretty sure there is something else to it

Comment: its not a seamless image so it might cause issues, but you can try increasing the size of the UV island

Comment: wow i have solved the problem, all you have to do is connect the image texture node to the normal input in the principal shader, and it worked like magic.